# snmp proxy in python

Tags: python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp

I need kind of snmp v2c proxy (in python) which:

- react on **snmpset** command
- read value from command and write it to yaml file
- run custom action (prefer in different thread and somehow reply success to snmpset command):

  - run another **snmpset** to different machine, or
  - ssh to user@host and run some command, or
  - run some local tool

and:

- react on **snmpget** command
- check value for requested oid in yaml file
- return this value

I'm aware of pysnmp but documentation just confuse me. I can image I need some kind of command responder (I need snmp v2c) and some object to store configuration/values form yaml file. But I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to implement all that with pysnmp. Technically, that would not be SNMP proxy but SNMP command responder.

You can probably take [this script](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/implementing-scalar-mib-objects.py#L99) as a prototype and implement your (single) `cbFun` which (like the one in the prototype) receives the PDU and branches on its type (`GET` or `SET` SNMP command in your case). Then you can implement value read from the .yaml file in the `GetRequestPDU` branch and .yaml file write, along with sending SNMP SET command elsewhere, in the `SetRequestPDU` branch.

The pysnmp API we are talking here is the low-level one. With it you can't ask pysnmp to route messages between callback functions -- it always calls the same callback for all message types.

However, you can also base your tool on the higher-level SNMP API which was introduces along with the SNMPv3 model. With it you can register your own SNMP applications (effectively, callbacks) based on PDU type they support. But given you only need SNMPv2c support I am not sure the higher-level API would pay off in the end.

Keep in mind that SNMP is generally time sensitive. If running local command or SSH-ing elsewhere is going to take more than a couple of seconds, standard SNMP manager might start retrying and may eventually time out. If you look at how Net-SNMP's `snmpd` works - it runs external commands and caches the result for tends of seconds. That lets the otherwise timing out SNMP manager eventually get a slightly outdated response.

Alternatively, you may consider writing a custom variation plugin for [SNMP simulator](https://github.com/etingof/snmpsim) which largely can do what you have described.

Comment: I saw this example and I got impression it's most suitable for me. By handler you meant cbFun? Should I define two cbFun for Get and Set or just one (with some if's inside)? How can I register / link them to transportDispatcher?